# Separate subnets for EKS control plane nodes (ENIs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

ENIs of control plane nodes are located on customer side of AWS account (in customer's own VPC). I see next in [AWS documentation](https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/networking/subnets/#using-only-private-subnets):

```
Kubernetes worker nodes can run in the cluster subnets, but it is not recommended. You can create new subnets dedicated to run nodes and any Kubernetes resources.
```

Does that mean that better to create separate subnets for ENIs of control plane nodes?